# Scroll to top in all app but save scroll position in one child module

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I need to save scroll position for child router module. My main router module use `{ scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' }`, but I do not know how to save scroll position only in one child module.

Comment: can you post how you configure your routes

Comment: I think forRoot you add this property, instead of this add child routes